# UICollectionViewCell with variable image size and AutoLayout

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm trying to display an `UIImageView` in a `UICollectionViewCell` that is loaded after the cell is displayed initially.

To not display a white are I use a fallback image. This has a different size than the image to displayed later.
The `sizeForItemAtIndexPath` thus is called at a time when the bigger fallback picture is displayed and returns a size that is too big for the eventually loaded image.

I've implemented a delegate to call a method after the image has finished loading. The delegate method then calls `reloadItemsAtIndexPaths` on the `UICollectionView` with the `indexPath` of the cell that finished loading. This happens only if the calculated `height` of the cell now differs from the value calculated before. The image is also stored in cache after the initial load. Together this ensures that the `reloadItemsAtIndexPaths` method is only called once.

Although this works in general I'm not sure if it's the best practice. It also doesn't have the best performance and with small network speeds my layout doesn't look very good.

Has anyone ever encountered the same problem or was trying to dynamically resize single cells in the `UICollectionView`?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with an image viewing app. I used `invalidateLayout` on the `collectionViewLayout` property of the collection view. It doesn't reload the cell, but calls `sizeForItemAtIndexPath` for the visible cells.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I also tried doing that, but wasn't satisfied with the result, because it happens quite a lot if you scroll through a list and every time you see "new" cells invalidate the layout.